# Set react context without useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

In my app I'm using a react context to store data like, is the page loading, is the network available and the title for the breadcrump.

```
const defaultValueForContext = {
    breadcrumb: null,
    networkState: window.navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline',
    isLoading: false
}
```

If the breadcrump in null I display a Header1, else Header2 with its title.
Header1 is a default header.
I set my breadcrump title in a component that I need it with useEffect.

`useEffect(() => setContext({ breadcrumb: { title: 'Breadcrump title' } }), [])`

My problem is where I have that Header2.
If I change something on that page that makes the component to re-render, first it takes that default header ( Header1 ) and when content renders, the useEffect sets the breadcrump title and that makes my header to 'flash'.

Is there a way to set the context value before the content renders ( without useEffect ), to get rid of that 'flash' ?

Comment: Can't you use `{ title: 'Breadcrump title' }` as the initial value? Why did you want to set it in an effect?

Comment: I have it null because in a header component, where I'm checking if breadcrump in null, I display one header and if I have a breadcrump I display a different header. I'm using this breadcrump in different components and to set the title I have to use useEffect. Without useEffect it's not wokring. I get an error:
`` Cannot update a component (`ContextProvider`) while rendering a different component (`Some_Component`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Some_Component`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org ``